# Initialize transactional Subscriber SQL server

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

As a requirement to get new data from publisher to subscriber. I used generate new snapshot and run log reader and run distribution agent.

Would like to know which option is we use to initialize Subscriber for all articles. I can see following 4 options.

Replication working good, But I heard from application team that they are facing some issue which compare data and load ETL job.

I used drop and recreate and it said primary key and foreign key relationship error. Then I used Truncate all table and load.

Is that correct method.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that correct method.

There is no single correct method, it just depends on your use cases.

The default option of `Drop existing object and create a new one` is pretty commonly what people use. But they typically also don't need to replicate the primary keys and foreign keys of their tables either, since you won't be writing any data to those tables on the Subscriber side. So you don't need those kind of data consistency checks on the Subscriber side, since it's already being handled at the source on the Publisher side.

Reasons you might not want to use that option is if you make any schema changes to the replicated tables on the Subscriber, such as custom indexes, triggers, change tracking features (such as Temporal Tables or CDC), etc. Then you'd have to write additional code to automatically manage removing / putting those things back in place, whenever reinitialization occurs. In such a case, the `Truncate all data in the existing object` might be the better choice for your use cases.

But there are drawbacks to that option as well. Certain schema changes at the Publisher will break your Replication topology if the option is set to Truncate only. For example, if a new column is added to the middle of a table in the Publisher, that would require the table at the Subscriber to be dropped and recreated. With the Truncate only option selected, your Replication topology will error out and stop syncing data. (This particular scenario assumes you're not using column filters on the Article being replicated.)

My recommendation is to stick to the default of `Drop existing object and create a new one` when possible (and don't replicate primary keys or foreign keys), and only switch it to `Truncate all data in the existing object` if you have an exception case for that Article, that you can't handle otherwise.

Comment: Thanks JD for the detailed information. It really helps me to understand now.

Comment: @Raja_mssqlDBA No problem! Not required, but feel free to upvote and / or mark the answer as accepted if you found it helpful, so others with similar questions see it as helpful too.